# How can I check if Diablo III works on a friend's computer?

Tags: diablo-iii

After watching me play, my brother would also like to purchase the game, but he has an older laptop, and cannot be sure that the game will be playable and/or have an acceptable frame rate.

I badly want him to try it, but he (perhaps rightly) can't justify spending the money until he can verify that it would run acceptably.

I bought a *digital* copy of Diablo III, and consequently wasn't given any *Guest Pass* keys for him to play the Starter Edition.

**What are our options?**

I can only think of one: re-download the game on his laptop, and sign in with my account. However, I'd prefer if I avoid this, lest there are any restrictions on number of activations, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do exactly as you suggested: re-download or copy your installation and install it (you don't need any code to do that), it's 100% legal.

You can then log on to your BattleNet account and try to play.

Answer (score 6):

The following website, Can You Run It, run checks on your computer (video card, cpu, memory, etc) and compares it against the minimum/suggested requirements of a ton of games, including Diablo 3. So far, it has provided me with good quality results.

http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/

What's most useful is the shaders check which tells you if the game will start or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That site 1- doesn't work on Macs, and 2- doesn't factor in integrated GPUs. It marked my base MacBook Pro with Intel HD3000 graphics as unsuitable, but it does work quite well for me

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who bought the boxed version also gets 3 trial passes to give to friends. Could get one of them and give it to your friend if you don't want to give him your battle.net credentials. I can give you one if you would like. (Currently at work and don't have it on me but will be home @ 6 PM EST)

Comment: that is the issue. I bought the digital copy, and really want my brother to try it, but I can't consciously give him my details :P I'd be willing to donate a small amount for your troubles. You can contact me here: http://about.me/simonsc

Comment: @Redandwhite No donation needed once I get home (in about 1 - 1.5 hours I'll send you an e-mail with the Key in it)

Comment: @Redandwhite Sent you the key